# How to notify an item has selected from data grid in wpf and using mvvm?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to notify that an item is selected from data grid because I am opening a modal window while selecting a item from data grid. I am editing selected item in modal window and due to which I do not want to RaisedPropertychanged mechanism for selected item because when I try to modify the selected item, it opens another modal window. I am now trying to use event trigger to fix this issue but getting errors. Below is related code:

**ViewModel:**

```
  public ObservableCollection<Student> sItems {
  get {
    return ssitems;
  }
 set {
   ssitems = value;
   RaisePropertyChanged( "sItems" );
  }
} 
private StudentsInformation studentInformation;
   public StudentsInformation studentInformationObject {
     get {
       return studentInformation;
     }
     set {
       studentInformation = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged( "studentInformationObject" );
     }
   }



public RelayCommand<Student> SelectionChangedCommand {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

These lines of code are in constructor:

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<Student>(
          item => {
            if( item != null ) {
              MessengerInstance.Send<Student>( item, "SelectedStudent" );
            }
          } );
```

This is collection which is bonded with datagarid.

**View:**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
                              IsReadOnly="False"  ColumnHeaderHeight="30"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStudentObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=myselect, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />-->
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Enrollment" Binding="{Binding enrollment}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding score}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding comment}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </DataGrid>
```

If I remove the trigger section then datagrid populated with desired data. If Include the trigger code then I get this error message:

*Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.*

I would like to know is there other ways to fix this kind of things. I am using MVVM Light toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That event trigger should be elsewhere. It should be placed in `Interaction.Triggers`

Use it like this:

```
<DataGrid...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

**UPDATE**

you probably should also use

```
<cmd:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionChanged" 
                        Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" 
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

and modify your Command in VM.

```cs
RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChangedCommand{get; private set;}
```

Comment: Thanks, It solves one problem. Now data grid is populating with data. But when I select the item in data grid, trigger does not work. Could you help me what is wrong with my triggering mechanism.

Comment: Well I am glad it helped. I don't know about your new problem because I am not familiar enough with MVVM-Light, but when I try this without sending param it works, but I think you should use `PassEventArgsToCommand=true` instead of `CommandParameter=..` and then modify your command in VM accordingly.

Comment: Thanks once again, I tried but getting this error message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs' to type 'XMLParsingExample.Model.Student"

Comment: @User1551892 You are kidding me right? :D [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) this is what is passed to your command as a parameter. And you are probably expecting Student. You have your selected student in args.AddedItems property Geeeez :D

Comment: Thanks, I did some mistake before.